# Android Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android and i'm following this [guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) to create a sliding tab with fragments. There are 3 tabs and 3 fragments created. However, I do not understand how can I start editing the individual fragments to do what I want.

Assume that I want the

- 1st fragment to have 2 textview & where can I write my logic codes?
- 2nd fragment to have 1 textview & where can I write my logic codes?
- 3rd fragment to have 4 textview & where can I write my logic codes?

Currently I have 3 java files:

- MainActivity

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TabLayout tabLayout;
  ViewPager viewPager;

  public static String POSITION = "POSITION";

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putInt(POSITION, tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(POSITION));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
      ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
      viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
              MainActivity.this));

      // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
      TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
      tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
      tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
      tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
  ```
- PageFragment

  ```
  public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
  public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

  private int mPage;

  public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
      PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
      fragment.setArguments(args);
      return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
      TextView textView = (TextView) view;
      textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
      return view;
  ```
- SampleFragmentPagerAdapter

  ```
  public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
  private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"Profile", "Shop", "History"};
  private Context context;

  private int[] imageResId = {
          R.drawable.ic_one,
          R.drawable.ic_two,
          R.drawable.ic_three
  };

  public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
      super(fm);
      this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return PAGE_COUNT;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      // Generate title based on item position
      return tabTitles[position];
  }
  ```

Comment: You have to create three fragments and put your logic in each fragment accordingly

Comment: see this tutorial http://www.android4devs.com/2015/12/tab-layout-material-design-support.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write you code logic in your `onCreateView()` or in `onViewCreated()` in every `fragment`.For example:

You have 2 `textView` in `FirstFragment` and one `Button` you can put your logic like this:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourXmlLayout, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

      //logic here
       yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
       yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }
```

and so on... for `SecondFragment` and `ThirdFragment`.

Comment: Inside the PageFragment.java in the tutorial page?

Comment: No inside this fragment is logic of opening the tabs . you must write you logic inside your fragment#1 , fragment#2, fragment#3

Comment: so i need to create another 3 .java to write my logic? how do i link them to the individuals tabs?

Comment: in your adapter this Profile,Shop,History must be a fragments yep , look in this tutorial was implement in that way https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: i have problems finding R.id.tvLabel. it is not found in the tutorial

Comment: please may i know what is the differences between my tutorial and yours?

Comment: @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
            default:
             return null;
            }
        }  This peace of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107244/discussion-between-zainau-and-kristiyan-varbanov).